# How to get output from a call in a different method (static void)?

Tags: c#, static-methods

I have two classes.
I am calling the method `ReadInteger()` from my `StartWholeNumbers()` which is in a different class.

For educational purposes, I am trying to get the boolean and integer number of TryParse.
I can return on or the other. But not sure how could I bring both of them. Is it even possible?

My code in class 1 (Input):

```cs
public static bool ReadInteger(string strInt, int choice)
{
    bool Booly;
    int x;

    Booly = int.TryParse(strInt, out choice);

    x = choice;
    return Booly;
}
```

My code in class2:

```cs
public void StartWholeNumbers()
{
    bool boolx;
    int choice = 0;

    Console.Write("Input: ");
    string Str = Console.ReadLine();

    boolx = Input.ReadInteger(Str, choice);

    Console.WriteLine("My bool is:" + boolx);
}
```

Comment: TryParse has nothing to do with the core issue. Replace TryParse with constant assignments and the “same issue” would be present. Static methods can access *static properties/fields* (in the question the assignments are to *local variables* which are only visible within the method), although perhaps ideally, the static methods would return values to avoid state side-effects.

Comment: For example, follow the TryParse approach and use `bool ReadInteger(.., out int value)` to propagate the value back that way, by assigning to the out variable before the ReadInteger method exits.

Comment: In the method only you can return one value but is possible combine using out parameter.
[out parameter modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier)

Comment: @MauricioKenny this is one of those rare cases where a C# 7 Tuple is an ergonomic alternative.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes, you have right. But we don't know what is the version framework he use for this code. I think the best choice is recode this and not use out parameters and split the code in two simple methods.

Comment: Fair enough but there is an official package from Microsoft for older. Net run times `system.ValueTuple`. Iirc Visual Studio will actually suggest installing it

Answer (score 2):

If i'm getting you right, your trying to return multiple results from a method,
You can use Tuple for that, or use a model class to return multiple results from your method,
but First you don't need to send (.., int choice) in your argument to the method, now let's refactor your method a bit to be.

```
    public static (int intResult, bool Parsedresult) ReadInteger(string strInt)
    {
        bool Booly;

        Booly = int.TryParse(strInt, out int choice);

        return (choice,Booly);
    }
```

now you can call it like this, and see the results

```
        var result = ReadInteger(yourString);
        int stringResult = result.intResult;
        bool isParsed = result.Parsedresult;
```

if Tuple is not in your version of .net, that mean you are using older version of .net framwork, but you still can get Tuple from NuGet by just searching for the name Tuple, you will get System.ValueTuple in search result.

Comment: Quite right. Note you can extract the results using `var (isParsed, parsedValue) = ReadInteger(yourString);`. Of course that's just a convenient shorthand and it's good to understand the long form as well

Comment: @AluanHaddad Even better for sure.

Comment: What's really nice is that it enables `var message = ReadInteger(yourString) switch { (true, var parsedValue) => $"Success: {parsedValue}", (false, _) => "Failure" }` but that's out of scope and I digress

Comment: @AluanHaddad lol your right it is out of scope, my head still get dizzy trying to wrap it with this new recursive patterns, unfortunately it's only available for C# v8 and above.

Answer (score 1):

the questions seems to be more about functions in general.
each function can have only one return type, so what you could do is create a class\struct for the return type you want:

```
public class ParseResult{
    public bool IsInt;
    public int ParsedInt;
}
```

create an instance, fill it with the result and return that..
if you don;t want to do that you could use an out type -
and you have to change is within the function (just like they do in tryParse)

```
public static bool ReadInteger(string strInt, out int choice)
{
    ...
}
```

as pointed out in the comments Tuple is also a (better the a custom type) way to return a set of values (this syntax is available as of c# 7):

```
    public static (bool, int) ReadInteger(string input)
    {
        int res;
        bool b = int.TryParse(input, out res);
        return (b, res);
    }
```

Comment: This was a primary motivation for adding tuples to the language. To avoid having to declare wrapper types. If you're going to illustrate the use of a custom type to wrap the result, it's also worth noting that a record can be used

Comment: in this specific case, an out parameter seems to be most relevant..
since he was asking for educational purposes I figured I'd add more options, 
I agree that tuple is also a better option than a custom class, I'll edit to add that option :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `out` with choice parameter that means your method will set the value of it.

**Note:** you shoudn't use this because `int.TryParse` will do like your method, Don't repeat the code

like this code:

```cs
// Add 'out' to parameter
public static bool ReadInteger(string strInt, out int choice)
{
    bool Booly;

    // int.TryParse will set value of choice
    Booly = int.TryParse(strInt, out choice);
    // Now choice is equals to the result of 'int.TryParse'

    return Booly;
}
```

#### Another way (suggested)

Or you can use structure or class to pass it like this

```cs
public struct Result
{
    public bool Booly;
    public int Choice;

    // constructor
    public Result(bool booly, int choice)
    {
        Booly = booly;
        Choice = choice;
    }
}

public static class Input
{
    public static Result ReadInteger(string strInt)
    {
        bool booly;
        int x;

        booly = int.TryParse(strInt, out x);
        // Now the value of x was changed by int.TryParse

        var result = new Result(booly, x);
        return result;
    }
}
```

And your first class

```
public void StartWholeNumbers()
{
    Result result;
    int choice = 0;

    Console.Write("Input: ");
    string Str = Console.ReadLine();

    result = Input.ReadInteger(Str, choice);

    Console.WriteLine("My bool is:" + result.Booly);
}
```